# Cplex Refiner: How to add existing Constraints only left- or right-handed?

Tags: cplex

The cplex refiner finds broken constraints. I'd like to show users detailed information about the actual conflict of their model.

Therefore i'd lik to splitt each constraint of the matrix into to separate constraints. the left-handed and the right-handed one. Example:

```
10 <= x1 <= 40
```

should turn into

```
10 <= x1 <= infinity
-infinity <= x1 <= 40
```

which is mathematically equal.

IBM's example about the cplex refiner (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21429472) uses this piece of code to take the constraints into account:

```
for (int c1 = 0; c1 < rng.Length; c1++)
{
    constraints[c1] = rng[c1];
}
```

I have slightly updated it, to split the constraints (please note: IBMs example heavily uses the index of the constraints array. all of this locs need to be updated as well)

```
for (int c1 = 0; c1 < rng.Length; c1++)
{
    constraints[c1] = cplex.Ge(rng[c1].Expr, rng[c1].LB);
}
for (int c1 = 0; c1 < rng.Length; c1++)
{
    constraints[rng.Length + c1] = cplex.Le(rng[c1].Expr, rng[c1].UB);
}
```

This is the model-file I used. (The bounds of x1 are in conflict with c3 and c4, obvisouly.)

```
 Maximize
      obj: x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3
 Subject To
      c1:  x2 + x3 <= 20
      c2: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
      c3: x1 <= 40
      c4: x1 >= 40
 Bounds
      10 <= x1 <= 10    
 Generals
      x1 x2 x3
 End
```

The updated version of the code with split constraints prints broken results (left hand sides first, then right-hand sides). it only shows x1 to be part of the conflict (thou it can not be the conflict on its own. it needs to have a buddy!)

```
Solution status = Infeasible
Model Infeasible, Calling CONFLICT REFINER
Number of SOSs=0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1*x2 + 1*x3) <= infinity
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1*x1 - 3*x2 + 1*x3) <= infinity
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1*x1) <= infinity
IloRange  : 40 <= (1*x1) <= infinity
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1*x2 + 1*x3) <= 20
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1*x1 - 3*x2 + 1*x3) <= 30
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1*x1) <= 40
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1*x1) <= infinity
Lower bound of x1
Upper bound of x1
Lower bound of x2
Upper bound of x2
Lower bound of x3
Upper bound of x3
Conflict Refinement process finished: Printing Conflicts
 Proved : Upper bound of x1
Conflict Summary:
 Constraint conflicts = 0
 Variable Bound conflicts = 1
 SOS conflicts = 0
Calling FEASOPT
```

The original version with both-handed constraints prints the expected results (c4 and x1 are part of the conflict)

```
Solution status = Infeasible
Model Infeasible, Calling CONFLICT REFINER
Number of SOSs=0
IloRange c1 : -infinity <= (1*x2 + 1*x3) <= 20
IloRange c2 : -infinity <= (1*x1 - 3*x2 + 1*x3) <= 30
IloRange c3 : -infinity <= (1*x1) <= 40
IloRange c4 : 40 <= (1*x1) <= infinity
Lower bound of x1
Upper bound of x1
Lower bound of x2
Upper bound of x2
Lower bound of x3
Upper bound of x3
Conflict Refinement process finished: Printing Conflicts
 Proved : IloRange c4 : 40 <= (1*x1) <= infinity
 Proved : Upper bound of x1
Conflict Summary:
 Constraint conflicts = 1
 Variable Bound conflicts = 1
 SOS conflicts = 0
Calling FEASOPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [RefineConflict](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refdotnetcplex/html/M_ILOG_CPLEX_Cplex_RefineConflict.htm) states the following for the `cons` parameter:

> An array of constraints. They may be IRange or IAnd constructs on a
>   set of ranges. Only constraints directly added to the model can be
>   specified.

In your modified snippet you are adding new constraints to the `constraints` array which have **not** been added to the model (e.g., you use the `Ge` method rather than the `AddGe` method).

I guess you could do something like the following:

```
cplex.Remove(rng); // First remove the original constraints
for (int c1 = 0; c1 < rng.Length; c1++)
{
    IRange tmp = rng[c1];
    // Now, add new constraints to the model and save them in the constraints array.
    constraints[c1] = cplex.AddGe(tmp.Expr, tmp.LB);
    constraints[rng.Length + c1] = cplex.AddLe(tmp.Expr, tmp.UB);
}
```

You should add the following line just before calling `RefineConflict` to make sure that the modified model looks like you expect:

```
cplex.ExportModel("modified.lp");
```

Comment: Yap. That's pretty cool. 
Removing the rng upfront works fine. Even restoring it at the very end (after using the refiner) by cplex.Add(rng) works fine.